# Restrict access to apache tomcat in local network

Tags: tomcat, local-area-network

I am setting up an apache tomcat webserver for my local network and I want to block any external access from outside of the local network (the internet) for security reasons.

Can I configure tomcat to do that?

**Edit:** I am using tomcat 8.0 on a windows machine.

Answer (score 4):

The server computer's OS firewall is probably sufficient to do what you're looking for. You don't mention the OS so I can't say anything specific. On a Linux machine you'd be throwing on some `iptables` rules on the `INPUT` chain. On a Windows machine you'd be creating rules in the "Windows Firewall with Advanced Security".

Answer (score 2):

You can configure Tomcat, your local system, or an interim firewall/router to do that. Since you gave no information on what version you're running, whether you're running Windows or Linux, or what networking equipment you have in place, I'll provide the information for restricting IPv4 access on Tomcat 8.0 itself.

In the conf/server.xml file, within the Catalina container (Engine, Host, Context, etc) that you want to restrict, add the following line:

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve" allow="127\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+|192\.168\.\d+\.\d+"/>
```

This will restrict access to that Catalina object to requests from only 127.*.*.* or 192.168.*.*.  Adjust as you see fit.

Further reading is available [HERE](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/valve.html#Access_Control)

Comment: I used `allow="127\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+|::1|0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1|10\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+|192\.168\.\d+\.\d+|172\.(1[6-9]|2[0-9]|3[01])\.\d+\.\d+"` to enable all the local networks.